# Handle Application class when system kill activity

Tags: android

My application have a class Applications extend Application like this.

```
public class Applications extends Application {


    // current station
    private Station currentStation;

   ...// Get set method for this Station object ...//

}
```

And in my first activity, i save the new value for object Station.

In second activity, i get the currentStation in application to do something in onCreate() like this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_editinfo);
        Applications app = (Applications) getApplication();
        Station current = app.getCurrentStation();

    }
```

When I enable "Don't keep activities" in Developer options to test the case that activity was killed. "app" return null when i resume this activity.

Anyone have ideas about handle data in Applications class when activity was killed to avoid crashes occur in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

"Don't keep activities" kills Activities, not Applications.

Try to do `Applications app = (Applications) getApplication();` again in `onResume()` and I think you'll get a valid object.